# Embed QR code in an existing document & read it back programmatically

Tags: c#, qr-code

There are several tools available out there to generate & scan QR code. My problem is slightly different.

Is there a way to embed QR code to an existing document? The position can be fixed (say top left corner) and any content there should be pushed down. The documents can be word / excel / pdf etc. Is it also possible to read such a document through a program & extract the QR code?

I am hoping for a .NET/C# answer but open for others as well.

Comment: This can be accomplished.  Perhaps it would be more helpful if you were to narrow your question a bit.  post research you've done or code you've found and the problems with it?

Comment: This is a good question, but too big for here. You can make a deep research via Google firstly.

Comment: I've spent last several days in finding about QR Code. There is http://www.tagmydoc.com/ but they do not provide libraries. Storing documents with them is not an option for us. Also looking into http://www.dynamsoft.com/Products/barcode-detection-decode.aspx but again seems to be only for scanning & not for embedding. I am also exploring http://strokescribe.com/en/about.html but it seems to be manual and not programmatic. Still exploring ...